# Jquery - call function when blur+clicking certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function when a certain field gets blurred, but only if a certain element is clicked. I tried

```
$('form').click(function() {
    $('.field').blur(function() {
        //stuff
    });
});
```

and

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
    $('form').click(function() {
        //stuff
    });
});
```

But neither works, I reckon it's because the events happen simultaneously?

Comment: You're _setting_ events within events here, you're not listening to them

Comment: Elements don't have "clicked" state.. unless you mean radio button and the proper term is "selected". So, what exactly do you mean in your question?

Comment: Nolgren - I have edited my answer, anyway I wouldn't implement this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input class="field" type="textarea" />
    <input class="field" type="textarea" />
</form>
<div class="click-me-class" id="click-me">Click Me</div>
<div class="click-me-class">Click Me Class</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
    $('#click-me').click(function(e) {
        foo = $(this).data('events').click;
        if(foo.length <= 1) {
            // Place code here
            console.log("Hello");
        }
        $(this).unbind(e);
    });
});
```

You can test it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/WfPEW/7/

Comment: That test-page is great! It doesn't really work though... What I want to happen is that when I don't click the other input, the alertbox should not be shown. In my tests it get's shown no matter where i click.

Comment: I see. I have updated the answer (including the jsfiddle link). If I understand correctly now, it should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, you can use `document.activeElement` to achieve this:

```
$('.field').blur(function(){
    if ($(document.activeElement).closest('form').length) {
        // an element in your form now has focus
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer because we have to take into account that the event is asigned every time.

It is not 100% satisfactory, and I don't recommend this kind of complicated way of doing things, but it is the more approximate.

You have to use a global variable to take into account the fact that the field was blurred. In the window event, it is automatically reset to 0, but if the click on "click-me" is produced, it is verified before the window event, becase window event is bubbled later, it happens inmediately after the "click-me" click event

`Working code`

```
$(window).click(function(e)
                {
  $("#result").html($("#result").html()+" isBlurred=0<br/>");
                        isBlurred=0;
                });

var isBlurred=0;

$('.field').blur(function() {
      $("#result").html($("#result").html()+" isBlurred=1<br/>");
    isBlurred=1;
});

    $('#click-me').click(function(e) {                  
        if(isBlurred==1)
        {
            $("#result").html($("#result").html()+" clicked<br/>");
        }

    });
```

".field" would be the input and "#click-me" would be the element clicked only just once.

Comment: This is similar to what I was working with for quite a while until I realized that on every blur, it makes another click handler for #click-me. So let's say you tab back and forth between the two .field's a few times before clicking #click-me, you will have #click-me's click function fire several times.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that my code only fixed clicking between elements and not tabbing. It's a sad day. I'm going to try to hammer this out some more.

Comment: I think I finally stumbled upon the right solution. See my update. I think it takes care of the issue I explained in my first comment here.

Comment: I have refactored my answer, anyway I wouldn't implement this kind of behaviour.